# can't get year factor to point on x axis

Tags: r, plot

I ran this:

```
> x<-tapply(positive$Emissions, as.factor(positive$year), sum)
> x
   1999    2002    2005    2008 
7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

Then ran:

```
plot(x)
```

And I keep getting this:

[image: Plot of tapply results]

I would like the x axis to show the year, not a numeric scale.  Less importantly, I'd like the y axis to not show engineering numbers, but something more readable.  I know I can divide by 1000 and get it to print a regular number.  But showing the year is more important.  I'm contrained to using the base plot functions.

The positive$year column is originally an integer.  The positive$Emissions column is numeric.

How do I force this?  I've had other plots that do this automatically, but were not operating off of tapply results.  I'm willing to pursue something besides the tapply function to get results, but previous attempts failed.

I tried this:

```
> plot(as.factor(positive$year),sum(positive$Emissions),ylab="Annual Emmissions in tons")
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

and understand the error, but don't know how to work around it, i.e. don't know how to get positive$year down to 4 values to match the 4 sums.

Data looks like this:

```
> head(positive)
   Emissions year
4     15.714 1999
8    234.178 1999
12     0.128 1999
16     2.036 1999
20     0.388 1999
24     1.490 1999
```

6 million rows, with 4 year categories.
Any pointers please.

Comment: Can you use `dput(x)` to provide your data (x)? I can't actually reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
positive <- data.frame(Emissions =rnorm(30), year=c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003))
positive

# Solution #1

x<-tapply(positive$Emissions, as.character(positive$year), sum)
x
plot(x=x,y=names(x),ylab="year",xlab="Emissions")
```

[image]

```
# Solution #2

x <- aggregate(positive,by=list(positive$year),sum)
plot(x=x$Emissions, y=x$Group.1) # same plot as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that `x$year` is a factor. If it is numeric, you shouldn't have this issue:

```
x <- read.table(text="   1999    2002    2005    2008 
7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206", header=F)
x <- t(as.matrix(x))
rownames(x) <- NULL
colnames(x) <- c("year", "emissions")
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x
#   year emissions
# 1 1999   7332967
# 2 2002   5635780
# 3 2005   5454703
# 4 2008   3464206
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Got it to work:
`code
> x<-tapply(positive$Emissions, as.character(positive$year),sum)
> x
   1999    2002    2005    2008 
7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206 
> plot(y=x,x=names(x))
`